# Asp.net : use of <%# or <%

Tags: asp.net

i'm having the following problem. 
I've a ASPX page with no databound and the following syntax:

```
<asp:label runat=server.... text='<%# MyFunction("parameter") %>' />
```

MyFunction is declared as follow:

```
protected function MyFunction(par as string) as string
  if par = "1" then
     MyFunction="something"
  else

  end if
end function
```

But ASP.NET don't evaluate MYFUNCTION .

What's i'm going wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<%#` is used for data binding expressions. Typically you'll see `<%# Eval("FieldName") %>`. If you're trying to call a method defined in your code-behind, you should use `<%= MyFunction("param") %>`

That said... you should consider a different approach. It would be better to do something as follows (using your existing example):

```
<asp:label name="MyLabel" runat="server" />
```

along with the following in your code-behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    MyLabel.Text = MyFunction("param")
End Sub

Protected Function MyFunction(par as string) as string
  if par = "1" then
     MyFunction="something"
  else

  end if
End Function
```

This approach ensures that your UI declaration knows nothing about methods defined on your code-behind, increasing the overall maintainability of your system.

Comment: mmm.. it doesn't work. In html, it is returning the string <%= MyFunction("param") %>

Comment: @stighy: that's because I didn't notice at first that it's inside the label declaration. It'll never work that way. You'll have to use the approach I've outlined in my edit.

Comment: Ok i've solved.. if i use <%= ...%> inside a control (label, literal) it return the string. But if use it standalone, without "binding" to the text proprety of a control, it works.
Thnks Randolpho!